# How to disable CodeIgniter SQL error message Dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I'm resting my SQL Auto increment value following SQL Command. But in SQL it's throw like an message. But In CodeIgniter get like Error Message.

This is my Code

```
$sql = "DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name, RESEED, 1)";
$res = $this->db->query($sql);
```

How can i reset my auto increment value without getting an error OR dynamically disable CI Error message.

Comment: can I use `simple_query` function in CI?

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?